# JavaScript losing "this" context, function inside class function

Tags: javascript, class, closures, this

```
class b { 
  constructor(){
    this.name = 'bar'
  } 
  b1(){
    console.log('here: ', this.name); 
    function c() {
      console.log('inside c: ', this.name)
    } 
    c();
  }
}

let a = new b; 
a.b1();

//output:
// here:  bar
// inside c:  undefined
```

In this case, when calling `a.b1()`, in the scope of function `b1`, the `this` context is bind to a. But when executing function `c` inside function `b1`, why the `this` context is lost? `this` suppose in the closure of function `c` ?

I know how to make it work (arrow function). Just wondering why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` isn't obtained from closure unless you use an arrow function, instead it as received by how the function is called.

Since `c` is called directly, this here refers to `undefined`.

You can declare c to be an arrow function to get this from the enclosing scope

```js
class b { 
      constructor(){
        this.name = 'bar'
      } 
      b1(){
        console.log('here: ', this.name); 
        const c = ()  => {
          console.log('inside c: ', this.name)
        } 
        c();
      }
    }
    
    let a = new b; 
    a.b1();
```

Comment: As regards to `c` is called directly: Isn't `c` called within the scope of `b1`?

Comment: The question isn't about from where but how.. if you look a it a.b1 will lead to b1 having this as `a`

Answer (score 0):

Function `c()` is not part of the class so you would need to use [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to pass in the class context as `this` or use arrow functions to declare it

```js
class b { 
  constructor(){
    this.name = 'bar'
  } 
  b1(){
    console.log('here: ', this.name); 
    function c() {
      console.log('inside c: ', this.name)
    } 
    c.call(this);
  }
}

let a = new b; 
a.b1();
```